# Как сделать историю вывода сообщений?

Tags: php

Суть в том, что есть переменная, которая дает текст. С каждым нажатием "кнопки" он меняется. Нужно все эти сообщения записать и выводить в виде истории. Сама история будет нужна только для текущей сессии, так что после использования ее нужно обнулить.

Подскажите, как это лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript + любой серверный язык (ну по традиции это обычно PHP). Ajax'ом просто инициализировать сессию и считывать ее же для вывода истории. Как известно, после закрытия браузера сессия уничтожается. Тем самым вам не надо будет заботиться об очистке...